Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 MacBook
I am facing this error on MacBook android studio
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':image_gallery_saver:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

I faced this error on windows and I fix it by download JDK 17 and located on android/gradle.properties like this
org.gradle.java.home = D:\jdk-17
but now when I did the same thing with Mac it shows the previous error.
export=JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Android/app/build.gradle
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8" // I tried to change this
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".."
        minSdkVersion 24 
        compileSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndkVersion >>
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
        }
    }

Using android studio ladyBug last version

This issue is related to  image_gallery_saver dependencies. seems its not updated. still you can use this as workarounf from their github page. : https://github.com/hui-z/image_gallery_saver/issues/339
